# Looping using for_each on terraform thrown me an error:Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required

Tags: regex, terraform

Given this data structure, which is a sops file, with this dummy structure:

```
 + data_output = [
      + "key=ASA/DCSDCS value=secret1",
      + "key=CEFD/CDSSD value=secret2",
      + "key=SDFSDF/CSDCSSCD Id value=secret5",
      + "key=BBB/CSDCSSC.yaml value=secret4",
      + "key=sdfksdflk/sfsdfsdf/sdfsdf/kjfdsakhfsd.yaml value=secret6"
    ]
```

Terraform will import it using sops as this:

```
+ data_output = [
      + "key=ASA.DCSDCS value=secret1",
      + "key=CEFD.CDSSD value=secret2",
      + "key=SDFSDF.CSDCSSCD Id value=secret5",
      + "key=BBB.CSDCSSC.yaml value=secret4",
      + "key=sdfksdflk.sfsdfsdf.sdfsdf.kjfdsakhfsd.yaml value=secret6"
    ]
```

Which leads me to do a lot of manipulation:

```
output "data_output" {
  value = [for k, v in nonsensitive(data.sops_file.secrets.data) : "key=${replace(replace(k, ".", "/"), "/yaml", ".yaml")} value=${v}"]
}
```

This first step, will convert all `.` to `/` and the last `/yaml` to `.yaml`, which is almost what i need but still, this is the produced output:

```
 + "original= aaaaa.bbbbbb.ccc.SECRET_NAME | modified=aaaaa/bbbbbb/ccc/SECRET_NAME",
 + "original= aaaaa.bbbbbb.ccc.dddd.SECRET_NAME.yaml | modified=aaaaa/bbbbbb/ccc/dddd/SECRET_NAME.yaml "
```

But still needing to extract the last piece as a name for use it in the creation of the secret vault (vault need the path + the secret name)
So, thanks to the help of the community here i came to this regex:

```
output "secret_output" {

value = [for k, v in nonsensitive(data.sops_file.account_secrets.data) : "path=${regex("/([^/]+)/?$", replace(replace(k, ".", "/"), "/yaml", ".yaml"))} | data = ${v}"]

}
```

And now is where i am stuck, because i got this error:
 `Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.`

But if is try with a normal string in terraform console, it works and in the way i want:

```
> regex("/([^/]+)/?$", "fgdfsdf/sfsdfsdfsd/dsfsdfsdfs/gff0fff-fff-ff-dsfssd-cscsd.yaml")
[
  "gff0fff-fff-ff-dsfssd-cscsd.yaml",
```

ideas? What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Wow....i answered myself.

Because of this:

> The return type of regex depends on the capture groups, if any, in the pattern:

> If the pattern has no capture groups at all, the result is a single string > covering the substring matched by the pattern as a whole.

> If the pattern has one or more unnamed capture groups, the result is a list of the captured substrings in the same order as the definition of the capture groups.
> If the pattern has one or more named capture groups, the result is a map of the captured substrings, using the capture group names as map keys.

I needed to remove the `()` to convert it from a list of string to a string.

Comment: If you need to use parentheses for precedence without creating a capture group then you can optionally use the "non-capturing sub-pattern" syntax: `(?:[^/]+)`. Though indeed in your case it seems the parentheses aren't needed at all because there aren't any operators applied to the sub-pattern as a whole.